# How do I save a section on my screen to the users images (in swift)?

Tags: swift

I want my user to be able to upload some images into a little square, and then I want all of them to be saved into one image on the user's iPhone.

I'm basically making an app the combines the users pictures beside each other (there's a ton of apps like that but I want to learn how they work), and then saves the total thing as an image on their phone.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You can edit your question to include your code and the results or errors you get when you run it.

Comment: I've not tried anything, as I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Save all your images in an array(arrImage) and use the following method to merge images

```
- (UIImage *) mergeImages:(NSArray*)arrImage{
  float width = 2024;//set the width of merged image 
  float height = 2024;//set the height of merged image 
  CGSize mergedImageSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
  float x = 0;
  float y= 0;
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mergedImageSize);
  for(UIImage *img in arrImages){
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x, y, width/arrimage.count, height/arrImage.count);
    [img drawInRect:rect];
    x=x+(width/arrimage.count);
    y=y+(height/arrImage.count))
  }
 
UIImage* mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();// it will return an image based on the contents of the current bitmap-based graphics context.
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return mergedImage;
}
```